# compress/decompress file in yii

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I want to use the extnsions provided in yii.

Please suggest some extensions in yii to compress/decompress uploaded files. and store on the server or directory and again to decompress them while downloading..

Here I have used an extension EAjaxUpload extension for uploading the file.

IN VIEW

```
<?php
$this->widget('ext.EAjaxUpload.EAjaxUpload',
        array(
       'id'=>'uploadResume',
                'config'=>array(
                       'action'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/index.php?r=site/word', 
                       'allowedExtensions'=>array("doc","docx"),
                       'sizeLimit'=>10*1024*1024,
                       'minSizeLimit'=>1*1024,
                       'multiple'=>false,
                       'onComplete'=>'js:function(id, fileName, responseJSON){alert(messages);}),
?>
```

IN CONTROLLER

```
    action{
    Yii::import("ext.EAjaxUpload.qqFileUploader");
    $folder = 'Resumes/';
            $allowedExtensions = array("doc","docx");
    $sizeLimit = 10 * 1024 *1024;
    $uploader = new qqFileUploader($allowedExtensions, $sizeLimit);
    $result = $uploader->handleUpload($folder);
    if(isset($result['success']))
            if($result['success']==true)
            {

                $fileSize=filesize($folder.$result['filename']);
            $fileName=$result['filename'];
                $mimetype = $fileName['mime']; 
            }
           // rename($folder.$result['filename'],$folder.$fileName);
           $return = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES);
       echo $return;

    }
```

.

Comment: I believe the Yii Cookbook has a recipe for this?

Comment: hi.. that dint help.. its for compressing the whole application output.. however i want to compress only the uploaded files and store it.. and decompress when downloading.. do you knw how to do that??

Answer (score 0):

You should use your systems tools, like tar or zip/unzip, from yii you could call this commands with [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or [system](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)